# Как поставить proxy на конкретное приложение. Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, telegram, unix, https, proxy

Подскажите, мне нужно подставить proxy на всю систему, вернее на telegram.
Я знаю про способы записать в `/etc/environment` или `export https_proxy` (только для консоли). 
Но, не работают они. В браузере - работают, а в самом telegram - виден реальный ip. 
К примеру, включал protonvpn и там сразу ip меняется, но нужно именно с прокси. 
Как подобное реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста. 
P.S способ поставить в самом telegram proxy - не то, что нужно

Comment: Через https-прокси можно пустить только https, а всю систему пустить через него технически невозможно

Comment: @andreymal
Я использовал виртуалку android  (genymotion) и вполне успешно https прокси ставились на все приложения. То есть на всю систему

Comment: @andreymal подправил комментарий

Comment: Значит вы на самом деле проверяли только те приложения, которые используют только https. А возьмите что-нибудь, что не использует https — например Telnet, SSH, да даже просто WebRTC в браузере — через них можно будет узнать реальный IP, потому что такие штуки технически невозможно пустить через https-прокси

Comment: @andreymal мне не нужно на всю систему, мне нужно конкретно на telegram. Подправил описание. Он внутри работает по тому же http (с самописным протоколом)

Comment: @andreymal нашел решение, держу вкурсе. Это через proxyChains можно реализовать.

Comment: proxyChains не поддерживает UDP и ICMP, так что тот же самый WebRTC в браузере пойдёт в обход прокси, ну или просто сломается. На звонки в телеграме это, возможно, тоже распространяется

Comment: @andreymal мне это только для регистрации акков надо, думаю подойдет